# Static page homepage not showing the_content

Tags: the-content, frontpage, customization

I must be doing something wrong here.

I setup my site with a static front page using front-page.php. I created a page in the admin with a title and chose the front-page.php in the template dropdown.

My title shows up fine, however the_content(); does not.

I'm not doing anything special as shown below.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Homepage
*/ ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="content">
<div class="welcome_area">
<div class="welcome_area_title"><?php the_title('');?></div>
<div class="welcome_area_text">
<?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
```

Any ideas why the content won't show?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't really have a Loop.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="content">
<div class="welcome_area">
<div class="welcome_area_title"><?php the_title('');?></div>
<div class="welcome_area_text"><?php 
if (have_posts()) {
  while (have_posts()) {
    the_post();
    the_content(); 
  }
} ?>
```

What is happening is:

1. You use `have_posts()` to check that you have post content. You can use an `else` clause to provide default content if you want.
2. You loop through that content using `while(have_posts())`
3. You run `the_post()` to setup the `$post` variable and also to increment the loop counter. Try that without `the_post()` an you get an infinite loop. This is the most critical part that was missing from your code.
4. Now that `the_post()` has run, your post template tags should work as expected.

I didn't edit your code too radically but I'd bring that `the_title` into the Loop as well, even if it seems to be working. It really [should be inside the Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) and it does not always work as expected outside of it.

### Reference

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Methods

Comment: What a silly mistake.  I can't believe I missed that, it was a long day.  Thanks for the catch.

Comment: You don't really need to use `have_posts()` in `front-page.php`; `front-pate.php` will only be used if there is a post to display. So you can just put `the_post()` in and leave the `if` and `while` statements out.

Comment: Technically that may be true Michael but you are going to start all sorts of bad habits and confusion with that recommendation.

Answer (score 4):

Well first of all, if you set your page as the static front page, you don't need to associate the template with the page, and the template doesn't need a header. WordPress automatically uses the `front-page.php` template for a static front page, as per [the template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy).

To answer your question though, you need to call [`the_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post) first to set up the global vars that [`the_content()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content) function relies on.